# What is the purpose of app engine's entrypoint?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I've scoured App Engine documentations for an explanation on what is an entry point, and I frankly have hit a wall. Was hoping someone on SO can provide an explanation of what and the purpose of an entry point is.

Comment: Does this help: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#entrypoint

Comment: kind of. I am using app engine to host my discord bot, and I followed a guide which places my main code (bot.py) script in place of entry point. I guess i'm confused because my code has nothing related to a command that listens on port 8080

Comment: Could you please share the guide and a code example for the (bot.py), to better understand your situation and try to help you with your concern about entry points and how to apply it for your code, if it is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An entrypoint is a [Docker command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) that is executed when the container starts, allowing you to configure a container that will run as an executable.

For App Engine the entrypoint  is specified in the `app.yaml` [file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#entrypoint), the command present in the entrypoint  field will be included in the entrypoint  of your app's Dockerfile, meaning that it is the one that will tell how the application has to be started when you are deploying it. The entrypoint  should start a web server that will listen on the [port 8080](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#listening_to_port_8080), which is the port used by App Engine to send requests to the deployed container. [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup) provides the `PORT` environment variable for ease of use.

For example:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

With this entrypoint  you are telling how you want the app to be started, in this case using [`gunicorn`](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/), and where do you want it to keep listening.

By default, this `gunicorn` command is the entrypoint used by App Engine when you do not explicitly set one in the `app.yaml` file.

You always need an entrypoint because all App Engine apps are deployed using Docker containers. Even if you only deploy a file with your code, App Engine will build a Docker container with the parameters set in the `app.yaml`, because when you deploy an app using App Engine, internally the process used is a [build](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/deploying-web-service#deploying_your_service), where the image is given by App Engine.

Also when you deploy an app with App Engine you will be able to find the related build if you go to the Cloud Build section in your GCP console, where you’ll find all the steps and information for the build of the Docker container where your App Engine is being deployed.

In conclusion, App Engine uses the entrypoint from Docker because internally what App Engine is doing while the deploying is using Cloud Build service to build a container image for your app with the information given in the entrypoint.

Comment: Thanks so much Vicky for the comprehensive response. What happens if we don't pass a web server, but instead pass a discord script i.e. bot.py? Nowhere in the bot.py file is there anything related to creating a web server i.e. Flask etc.? Excuse me if this is an extremely noob question. I'm quite new to all of this, including Docker. Also I always thought Docker was related to Cloud Run, not necessarily App Engine.

Comment: Did you tried to deploy it? Could you please share the code or the documentation you have been following to be able to understand better your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The entrypoint tells the container what to do when it is run.  I see it most frequently with [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint), but other container formats will have something equivalent.

For App Engine, the key thing the entrypoint setting does is start the HTTP server which listens for requests.  Here is the [Python documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup) describing the entrypoint, but there are also links for other runtimes at the top of the page.